# Python adding whitespace prior to print statement

Tags: python

My python code:

```
guess = 50
high = 99
low =0
hilo = 0
print ('Please think of a number between 0 and 100!')
while hilo != 'c':
    print ('Is your secret number ' + str(guess) + ' ?')
    print ("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low."),
    hilo = raw_input ("Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
    if (hilo != 'c' and hilo != 'h' and hilo != 'l'):
        print 'Sorry, I did not understand your input.'
    if hilo == 'l':
        low = guess
        guess = (high + low) / 2
    if hilo == 'h':
        high = guess
        guess = (high + low) / 2
print ('Game over. Your secret number was: ' + str(guess))
```

prints this:

```
Please think of a number between 0 and 100!
Is your secret number 50 ?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.
Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
 Is your secret number 25 ?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.
Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. l
 Is your secret number 37 ?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.
Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.
```

The first execution of the following line of code is aligned with the rest of the output but all subsequent executions have a single space in front.

```
print ('Is your secret number ' + str(guess) + ' ?')
```

What is causing that?

Comment: I can not reproduce this behaviour on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.8

Comment: I'm using Canopy version 1.5.2.  Maybe it's specific to that.  I will try on another IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Run this instead, you have a comma at end of line (at the third print statement):

```
guess = 50
high = 99
low =0
hilo = 0
print ('Please think of a number between 0 and 100!')
while hilo != 'c':
    print ('Is your secret number ' + str(guess) + ' ?')
    print ("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.")
    hilo = raw_input ("Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
    if (hilo != 'c' and hilo != 'h' and hilo != 'l'):
        print 'Sorry, I did not understand your input.'
    if hilo == 'l':
        low = guess
        guess = (high + low) / 2
    if hilo == 'h':
        high = guess
        guess = (high + low) / 2
print ('Game over. Your secret number was: ' + str(guess))
```

Comment: Removing that will fix the issue but cause  a blank line between the output statements which I cannot have.

Comment: I don't see any blank lines, sorry, you will have to repost as a separate case...maybe even edit your original post.

Comment: Just use IDLE for the moment, might have something to do with Canopy; works for me with IDLE and through cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a Canopy specific issue as it's not being reproduced in other IDE's.  Canopy technical support has been notified and they are working on a resolution.